# Named Credential Auth 2.0 JWT Token giving empty error: "Unable to complete the JWT token exchange. Error: . Error description: ."

Tags: rest-api, api, oauth2, namedcredentials, externalcredentials

My JWT token is retrieved using only the following parameters in a json body:

```
{
   "username":"blabla",
   "password":"blabla"
}
```

I don't need the standard JWT parameters but if they are in the body it doesn't give an error, if try in postman. I would like to use a named credential to manage the retrieved token that refreshes every 20 min, so I don't store it in a custom object or split in 3 fields in a custom setting.
The External Credential is configured as Auth 2.0 and JWT Bearer Token and the username and password are configured as JWT Body Claims. The principal is added in a permission set assigned to my user.
Can anyone help me achieve this requirement?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.